# Changing jQuery load in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load, location-href

I was using a php switch to include my different views. Yesterday I decided to break up with php includes and only work with jquery 'load ins'. I already used jquery for this in my previous code, but only for js users.
Im not used to work with php so I decided to not give a shit about them and force them to enable it, using a `<noscript>`-tag.

A good friend of mine helped me with the js code to handle it. Now, since I dont want to use **`href="?content=view"`** anymore, Im kinda hamstrung. I already tried to change the stuff that has to be changed by myself but I dont get it work correctly.

I really hope someone of you can help me out with this.

Old working script for the links `<a href="?content=view">Anything</a>`:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() 
            var inc=  this.href.split('=').pop(),
                  href = "inc/" + inc + ".php"
            $('.con').hide().load(href, function(){
                $('.con').fadeIn();
            })
            document.title =  'Domain.com | ' + firstToUpperCase(inc)
            location.hash = inc
            return false;
        });

function firstToUpperCase( str ) {
    return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}
```

The new links are placed in the forder called views, `<a href="view.html">Anything</a>`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to edit this to make it work for anything.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, this should work:

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault() 
            var inc=  this.href.split('.').shift(),
                  href = "inc/" + inc + ".php"
            $('.con').hide().load(href, function(){
                $('.con').fadeIn();
            })
            document.title =  'Domain.com | ' + firstToUpperCase(inc)
            location.hash = inc
            return false;
        });

function firstToUpperCase( str ) {
    return str.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: I changed inc/ to views/ and ".php" to ".html". When I alert(inc);, I get /views/anything THats good, but it has to have an .html/.php at the end.